# Is there a situation that the function CreateFile returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and GetLastError() returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS

Tags: windows, createfile, kernel32, getlasterror

I searched MSDN about

```
HANDLE WINAPI CreateFile(
  _In_     LPCTSTR               lpFileName,
  _In_     DWORD                 dwDesiredAccess,
  _In_     DWORD                 dwShareMode,
  _In_opt_ LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
  _In_     DWORD                 dwCreationDisposition,
  _In_     DWORD                 dwFlagsAndAttributes,
  _In_opt_ HANDLE                hTemplateFile
);
```

and if `dwCreationDisposition` == `CREATE_ALWAYS` or `OPEN_ALWAYS`, it says

> Creates a new file, always. If the specified file exists and is
>   writable, the function overwrites the file, the function succeeds, and
>   last-error code is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183). If the specified
>   file does not exist and is a valid path, a new file is created, the
>   function succeeds, and the last-error code is set to zero. For more
>   information, see the Remarks section of this topic.

and

> Opens a file, always. If the specified file exists, the function
>   succeeds and the last-error code is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183).
>   If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable
>   location, the function creates a file and the last-error code is set
>   to zero.

So I'm not sure that if the function failed, would `GetLastError()` be `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` ?

Please give me an example if so.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Fast answer: No.

According to what's specified:

`ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` shall be returned by `GetLastError()` right after a `CreateFile()` call **only when** the file exists, `dwCreationDisposition` is set to `CREATE_ALWAYS` or `OPEN_ALWAYS` and the `CreateFile()` **succeeds**.

If `CreateFile()` fails with `CREATE_ALWAYS` or `OPEN_ALWAYS` set as `dwCreationDisposition`, then `GetLastError()` shall return the appropriate last-error code indicating the reason why the file could not be opened, but that cannot be `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` as the user specifically requested to open or create the file, regardless if it exists or not.

This shall not be confused with the return value of `GetLastError()` when a call to `CreateFile()` with `dwCreationDisposition` set to `CREATE_NEW` fails because the file exists. In this case, `GetLastError()` shall return `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS` and **never** `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can have the call to CreateFile with OPEN_ALWAYS fail returning NULL handle and get error 183. This happens to me when I call CreateFile with OPEN_ALWAYS specifying a file in a directory that doesn't exit.

example:
`C:\NonExistingDirectory\Myfile.txt`

I'm not sure if this is a consistent behaviour on different Windows versions. I got it on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Intermittently.

I'm getting users complaining about an intermittent issue. I've tracked it to the following call in our code.

```
   HANDLE hInputFile = ::CreateFile("path_to_file_i_want_to_read", 
                        GENERIC_READ,
                  0,
                  NULL,
                  OPEN_EXISTING,
                  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY,
                  NULL);
```

Sometimes (I still don't understand why, not all users are reporting the problem) this call will return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. The error code is `183 "Cannot create a file when that file already exists"`. Which is silly because I'm trying to open a file that was created moments before (It exists) and I want to read it.